# Calculating vector norm in Python using functions

Tags: python

I am calculating the vector norm using functions in Python. The `calculate_vector_norm` receives a vector as a tuple and return a float containing the norm of the vector.

```
import numpy as np

def calculate_norm_vector(vector):
    """
    Function that calculates the norm of a vector
    Args:
    - vector (tuple): the vector used to calculate the norm.
    return:
    float containing the norm of the vector.
    """
    ret=np.zeros(vector.shape[1])
    for i in range(vector.shape[1]):
        ret[i]=np.linalg.norm(vector[:,i])
    return ret
```

When I execute this using

```
calculate_norm_vector((2, -2, 3, -4))
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-5-810f2e17d3ce> in <module>()
----> 1 calculate_norm_vector((2, -2, 3, -4))

<ipython-input-4-5ec67b4c4513> in calculate_norm_vector(vector)
      9     float containing the norm of the vector.
     10     """
---> 11     ret=np.zeros(vector.shape[1])
     12     for i in range(vector.shape[1]):
     13         ret[i]=np.linalg.norm(vector[:,i])

AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use

```
len(vector)
```

instead of

```
vector.shape[]
```

bc, a tuple has no attribute shape and as your input is a 1d Tuple you can simply get the length.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the other answer, you could also create a numpy array

```
calculate_norm_vector(np.array([2, -2, 3, -4]))
```